# In RightAWS Gem SDB SELECT only returning 100 records at a time. I would like to select more

Tags: ruby, amazon-simpledb

We use SDB to store lots of data and currently I'm using the RightAWS gem for Ruby to access that data.  I'm trying to get the results of a query which returns about 16,000 items.  This process takes a long time because I only get 100 back each token and, as a result, 160 requests must be made.  The documentation says:

> The limit is the maximum number of results to return (default: 100,
>   max. 2500).

I've done this in my own php code, but I can't find a way to make RightAWS do it.  Is there a way, or will I have to do something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I feel really silly.  It turns out that all I had to do was add "LIMIT [number]" at the end of my query.  I was sure I tried that but I guess not.